# $ not defined, no def error in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have linked the jquery cdn to the HTML file, as well as double checked my code.  What exactly do I have going on here that I do not see.
Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".menu-icon").on("click", function () {
        $(".navlist").toggleClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
        });
    });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script href="mainjs.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Chase Quinn</title>
    <link rel=" icon " href="Assets/favicon.png " />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Do+Hyeon " 
    rel="stylesheet " />

</head>
```

I have linked the cdn in both my footer and my header, to no avail.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: If `$` is not defined, then, jQuery is most definitely not loaded. As @CertainPerformance said, please post your HTML page or set up a snippet/jsfiddle so that we can see it by ourselves ;)

Comment: @sjahan I just updated the post.

Comment: @ChaseQuinn unfortunately, that's not enough: where are your `<script>` tags? are they valid? that's the true question here! This part is just fine, but not related to jQuery loading.

Comment: @sjahan okay, I updated the <head> html

Comment: Is your problem is $ not defined only?

Comment: @ChaseQuinn Is your HTML page loaded using HTTPS or HTTP? Chrome could reject an HTTP request if the page is in HTTPS: maybe try to add an extra S to the CDN URL! Extra question: do you have any other error/warning in the console of the devtools?

Comment: Is this the only JS you have? Are you sure you are not overwriting `$` elsewhere?

Comment: It states that I am missing strict statement

Comment: Try this link https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js add the script tag at the end not at the headerand no need to give `type` in the script tag . This is the current version

Answer (score 0):

You must import `JQuery library` in your html file. 
Simply add this line of code to your `head` tag at the end, Or put it before `</body>` tag and **before** custom script you coded!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I changed my import to the newer version, and yet it still has the same issue.  Did I mistype something that I am overlooking?

Comment: Replace this line of code with your code, remove `type="text/javascript"` @ChaseQuinn

Comment: Removing `type="text/javascript"` does not help? @ChaseQuinn

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is `$` not defined than try this code instead of previous.

```
(function($){
  $(".menu-icon").on("click", function(){
    $(".navlist").toggleClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
   });
})(jQuery);
```

---

If this code above isn't working than you can try to use `jQuery.noConflict()`

Just add a `$` variable.

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu-icon").on("click", function(){
    $(".navlist").toggleClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
   });
});
```